# Can I haz stinkin' silver tag badge, plz?

Tags: bug, tags, tag-badges

Yup, the [tag scoring script is struggling to keep up with Stack Overflow's dataset](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226681/tag-scores-are-not-updated-and-the-issue-is-getting-worse). But when it *does* successfully run and you reached the threshold for a tag badge, you are at least [awarded your badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/3949/tuples?userid=100297).

So why haven't I been awarded a silver tag badge for [python-requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-requests)? I meet [all the criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions#68395):

- There are more than 100 questions tagged [python-requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-requests).
- I have a score of [exactly 400](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python-requests/topusers).
- I have [105 non-wiki answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A100297+%5Bpython-requests%5D+is%3Aanswer+wiki%3Ano) on the tag.

Comparing my [tag scores](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters?tab=tags&sort=votes) to the realtime API output (via [Awesome Poodles' awesome script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/179402/140890)) it is clear the tag scores have updated, but what happened to awarding tag badges?

Having scanned [all silver badges from `.htaccess` up to `cxf`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=silver) I cannot seem to find anyone receiving tag badges more recently than 2 days ago.

A few more examples beyond just me:

- Hans Passant should have earned a bronze badge for [icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/icons) (2 upvotes yesterday to push him to 100).
- SLaks should have earned a bronze badge for [namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/namespaces) (qualifying tag score, haven't found yet if a question was retagged or similar to push him over)
- Stephen C should have earned a bronze badge for [loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loops) (2 upvotes for a new post yesterday to push him to 101).

Comment: Wait till you have a score of 401 and still don't have the badge.

Comment: @ChrisF: I've had **plenty** of badges awarded for exactly 100, 400 and 1000 scores. The criteria are met.

Comment: OK. Then when did you hit 400. Was it sometime today?

Comment: The tag score doesn't update if you didn't hit 400 before the script runs, Chris. The 400th vote came in [day before yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16145116/python-requests-post-data-from-a-file/16145232#16145232) (20:52, says my reputation tab). But the tag scores script failed to run yesterday.

Comment: Coincidentally, I *just now* received vote 401 on that tag.

Comment: Perhaps they are out of silver?

Comment: Either that, or python ate all the [hamsters](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/96356/158667).

Comment: @Mat I can't believe that question was closed as unproductive. I don't believe I've ever seen a more useful post.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The smoking gun about a problem here is that you received the 400 day before yesterday. I'm pretty sure the script runs once per day... if you don't have it tomorrow (after getting 401 today) then there is definitely a problem.

Comment: @durron597: The badge awarding is normally part of the tag-score calculations, which runs once a day (at 03:00 UTC) but [has been failing a lot (on Stack Overflow) as of late](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226681/tag-scores-are-not-updated-and-the-issue-is-getting-worse); if the tag score script fails, you don't get tag badges. But this is this the first time I've seen the tag score script run but not see tag badges awarded.

Comment: @durron597: The tag-score calculations failed yesterday, as is now regular, the surprise here is that it *did* run early this morning but the tag badges themselves have not been awarded. Either the two events are run separately and now the tag badge awarding script has started failing independently (perhaps because the tag scoring script took so long the badge awarding script ran too early to see the updated scores), or something else broke.

Comment: "real time" my Matlab tag count is at 403 (according to the helpful script linked above) - but the "counter" seems stuck at 399. Still. So the script is still struggling, apparently. Just one more bit of noise to add to the chorus. This still needs work.

Comment: @Floris: yes, you are caught by the longer-running problem of the tag counts not updating. My issue here is that even if they *do* update, badges are not being handed out *still*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I guess I will have to get internal satisfaction knowing I answered a lot of Matlab questions, despite of the lack of shiny recognition. Works for me - I am not trying to monetize my profile anyway.

Comment: @Floris: exactly. I just reported the bug as it was a new development; a change from how it was b0rken before.

Comment: sounds like the script is broken/bombing out before it gets to you.  Eventually you will get your badge.

Comment: @MarshallTigerus: Sure, and that's no problem, really. I just wanted the devs to be aware the issue exists.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think most of the update scripts are unstable for the site.

Comment: ..the script finally *just* ran. I'm willing to bet that it won't run for another week or so.

Comment: @JoshCrozier: I got badges this time round (6 in total!). I do hope the team finds a solution some time soon, because this is only going to get worse. It is a scaling problem, Stack Overflow has gotten too big for the current approach.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour - you've only got **75** non-wiki answers (double check the tooltip) not the 80 you need for the silver badge.

Comment: You need to limit it the answers; `is:a`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters doh, I never realized questions added to that count, thank you! It has almost been two years and I am still figuring stuff out :-(

Comment: This problem seems to be back (if it was ever resolved) -- how do we handle that on Meta, especially considering that this question is > 1 year old and without an answer? A new question?

Comment: @AnandaMahto: it is indeed back. It comes back from time to time, then disappears again. Let's wait another few days before ringing the alarm bells, it may just go away again.

Comment: @MartijnPieters http://www.xkcd.com/1495/

Comment: @ChrisF Wait until you get 404: `404 Badge Not Found` :)

Comment: @MartijnPieters [Still an issue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318122/2069064) it seems.

Comment: @Barry it is a recurring issue. It'll sort itself out.

Comment: This seems to be getting worse. I started monitoring my html badge at least two weeks ago and I don't think it has update once in that time.

Comment: @Turnip: are you sure? My tags have been updating regularly currently. And the [output of Awesome Poodles' script](http://output.jsbin.com/azeqec/12?sitename=stackoverflow&userid=746736) agrees with the displayed scores on your profile.

Comment: @MartijnPieters maybe it's me misunderstanding the stats but my profile says "632" (this hasn't changed in weeks) but the "Select your next tag" popup says "660" (this updates more frequently) - Screenshot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/IhIP1.jpg

Comment: @Turnip: right, so the *progress tracker* is stuck. My post here is about the overall tracking of tag scores. I missed that that tracker is indeed stuck on your profile. See [Tag badge progress bar stuck](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/321981)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yeah, to be honest I only just noticed the correct score on the pop up this morning. I didn't realise they were showing different values.