# Can I haz tag badge?

Tags: bug, tags, tag-badges

I just got a notification that I earned the silver [c++14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) badge, so I decided to check my status on all my other tags and I noticed:

[image]

I have 89 answers in [pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pointers) for 401, 41 answers in [algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algorithm) for 112, and 37 answers in [operator-overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/operator-overloading) for 104. But no silver badge for the former or bronze badge for the latter two.

It's not that the tag update system isn't running - I just got a new badge. Just not all of my new badges... What's up?

Comment: Don't you also need to have a positive record on the tag?

Comment: @star2wars3: Barry's record is quite positive, over 400 net upvotes for pointers tag.

Comment: Same problem [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253587/2301450)

Comment: i want one too..