# Tag badge progress bar stuck

Tags: bug, tags, badge-progress

In user activity page, there is a progress bar showing progress towards the next tag badge. Mine progress bar seems to be stuck on an old value, though.

[image: example]

As you can see on the screenshot, my answer score is 114 but the progress bar only shows 103. I'm aware that the statistics are recomputed in batch once in a while, but this situation hasn't changed for several weeks now.

Is this a bug, or is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: Related: [Vote count and badge scores not updating](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317757/vote-count-and-badge-scores-not-updating)

Comment: Yep, seems like the same thing, thanks.

Comment: Actually, the two issues are related, but *separate*. Tag scores have been updating properly recently, but the progress trackers *seem to be stuck*.

Comment: Same report [over on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267818/next-tag-badge-panel-score-and-answers-counter-discrepancy) (still open).