# Confused in score of next tag badge

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, badge-progress

The below image is showing a 17/100 score for the CSS tag:

[image]

When I click on the setting button that is on the left side of the CSS tag, it gives me a 22/100 score for the CSS tag:

[image]

Is it a bug or something else? I am not getting it.

Comment: Yes, this is a [known](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267818/next-tag-badge-panel-score-and-answers-counter-discrepancy) [bug](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321981/tag-badge-progress-bar-stuck).

Comment: [caching?](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/)

Comment: so what's is the score of mine for css tag..? first one or second one?

Comment: Just change to a different badge and then change back to the CSS badge and it should start updating again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updating the tracking of badges is an expensive operation (database resource wise - updates need to happen for everyone), so it only happens once a day for everyone (we are looking at making it happen more often).

However, when showing the list of trackable badges, these are shown using the latest available information, so are up to date.

Likewise, when you select a different badge to track, we update that badge information, which is why if you select a different badge, then select the original back you will see it is updated.